# Oracle Apex: How do I tell Apex to use the value from a column of another table?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

FIRST, we are not using code. We are using the Apex GUI to set up the database. I need the column of one table to take the value from the column of another table. If it's a Trigger that I have to create, then it will probably require the code.

For example, I have a table "customer" in which there is indicated under the "member" column a yes or no.

I want the table "order" that also has a "member" column automatically take the value from the table "customer"'s "member" column whenever a new row of data is input for the table "order."

Do I do that under "constraints," because when I try to create a foreign key of the member column, it keeps giving me an error.

Do I do that under "Triggers?"

Please understand, I do not understand the code very well. When someone says something like

COMMAND table1 s
(
  Whatever comands
);

I have no idea what the "s" is for. And I'm pretty sure there's a lot of other stuff I don't quite understand either. I have been introduced to MySQL, but it apparently has some differences to Apex Oracle.

Thank you.

Comment: You should elaborate on why you want to duplicate this flag from customer to order. Why do that? An order is (probably) linked to a customer, so it doesn't (necessarily) make sense to copy the field. It's usually a bad idea to start duplicating data, and even worse when you're mixing in triggers.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger is one way to do it.  Assuming that the `order` table includes a `customer_id` column or something similar that identified the customer, you would create a before-insert, for-each-row trigger that includes a statement like this:

```
SELECT customer.member INTO :new.member
FROM customer WHERE customer.customer_id = :new.customer_id
```

Frankly, you'll need to do some reading to learn how to write proper triggers if this is something you want to do.

Assuming you will be building an Apex application to enter orders, another approach would be to have the relevant page query the necessary information from `customer` when it loads (probably into hidden page items), then include them in the insert statement.

Again, if you don't know how to do this, you need to do some study if you are planning to use Apex to accomplish anything useful.

A foreign key here is not appropriate.  The column referenced by the foreign key must be unique; since `member` has only two values, many customers will have the same value, so it is not a unique field.

A foreign key would be appropriate for the field in `order` that identifies the specific customer, however.

Answer (score 0):

You need Master-Detail page. Press `Create page` -> `Form` -> `Master Detail Form`, then choose:

- Step `Master Table and Columns`: `Table/View name` - `customer`, `Select Columns` - choose desired columns of table `customer` that user will edit.
- Step `Detail Table and Columns`: `Table / View Name` - `order`, `Select Columns` - choose desired columns of table `order`.
- Step `Define Primary Key`: choose primary key for both tables (or use option `Managed by ROWID`)
- Step `Primary Key` - I recommend to use previously created sequence (go to `Object Browser`).

In all other steps you can choose values by default. After this steps you will have two pages (or three, depending on what you choose in a wizard). One page allows user to change data in the table `customer`, second - to change data in the table `order`, and this data will be linked with the table `customer` automatically.